# Canadian witness/suspect in an American crime

Tags: criminal-law

If Montana police want to question a Canadian citizen about a crime committed in the US, could the Canadian be compelled to cooperate?

Comment: Where is the Canadian? In Montana?

Comment: To be clear, Canadian citizens who are physically located in the U.S. could be compelled to the same extent as U.S. citizens except that they could ask a Canadian embassy or counsel to provide legal/diplomatic assistance in looking after their rights (U.S. citizens could gain access to a public defender only if charged with a crime and they are indigent.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kidnapping_of_Sidney_Jaffe  is slightly relevant...

Comment: @ohwilleke : Did you mean "consul"?

Comment: @MichaelHardy I did. But, I caught the spelling error only after it was too late to correct.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes the Canadian is in Canada and is unwilling to testify because if those two facts are not the case, then there is no reason to be asking a question.

The US is a party to the Convention of 18 March 1970 on the Taking of Evidence Abroad in Civil or Commercial Matters (aka the Evidence Convention). Unfortunately for you, Canada is not. Nor is Canada a party to the Inter-American treaty dealing with the same issue.

Thus, when a potential witness is unwilling to cooperate, you must rely on [letters rogatory](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/legal-considerations/judicial/obtaining-evidence/preparation-letters-rogatory.html). This is, by the way, how you would go about obtaining evidence in any foreign country not party to a treaty on the taking of evidence with the United States. The process of executing this can be costly and lengthy (a year or more perhaps). The reason for that is because this is done via diplomatic channels in the interest of preserving international comity (goodwill, friendly relations between countries) where a relevant treaty and process does not exist.

You should include in any letters rogatory:
- a statement saying that in the interest of justice a request is being made for international judicial assistance
- a summary of the case, including identification of parties and the claim(s) and relief sought
- type of case
- the sort of assistance you would like (do you want testimony? document production? service of process?)
- name, address, title, etc., of the person from which you are seeking to collect this from
- list of questions you intend to ask
- statement from requesting court (where the litigation is filed) expressing the court’s agreement to reciprocate this sort of assistance if such occasion should arise
- statement from requesting court or party that costs incurred fulfilling this request will be reimbursed

It must be signed by a judge. Then, along with relevant fees which can be found under the Schedule of Fees at 22 CFR 22.1, send your request to:

ATTN: Judicial Assistance Officer
US Department of State
Office of Legal Affairs, (CA/OCS/L)
SA-17, 10th Floor
2201 C St. NW
Washington, DC 20522

Include a cover letter with the details outlined on the State Dept.’s website.

Then, the State Department will transmit the request to the Canadian authorities through diplomatic channels. Then, the foreign court will send the executed request back to the State Department and you will be notified.

NOTE: please check the State Dept.’s website and/or consult an attorney if you move forward with this. The above is fairly detailed but should not be considered legal advice nor should it be relied upon in your legal proceeding.

[Also note:](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/20141008173150-304587-planning-an-international-deposition-guidelines-for-attorneys) the exact procedures will vary by jurisdiction and I’m not sure where in Canada may be relevant to you. That said, in some civil law countries, the foreign judge may end up questioning the witness with the US attorneys submitting written questions to the judge. Just a heads up there, too.

Comment: Shorter answer (speaking as someone who has dealt with this in a civil case): No. The Canadian cannot be compelled to cooperate in the time frame necessary to get an answer within a reasonable time, at least without the cooperation of Canadian law enforcement that chooses to join the investigation.

Comment: Well, of course there was no timeframe given in the question. Also, in reality the Canadian can be compelled assuming the Canadian courts don’t find anything objectionable about the request from the US court, as was stated.

Comment: Usually the time frame will be dictated by speedy trial rights and/or the need to get information while the trail is hot enough to follow in practice. Even if the Canadian courts don't find anything objectionable, running through the process takes months.

Comment: Yeah, the answer indicates it could even be a year or more. Are you saying that if you have a key witness in a non-treaty foreign country, you would just be out of luck?

Comment: Also, I did answer in the context of a civil case (although I do notice the word suspect in the original question). There is no right to a speedy trial in civil cases. Those can take years already, not really an in-and-out process.

Comment: Yes. You would usually be out of luck unless a Canadian law enforcement agency joins the investigation or the U.S. State Department really puts pressure on the Canadian government to cooperate.

Comment: I was assuming a criminal case.

Comment: So are you disagreeing with the answer? Because I think it says exactly what you’re saying while also laying out steps to complete the process the poster asked about?

Comment: No. Not disagreeing. Just expanding on your answer to get to the practical bottom line a criminal case.

Comment: Gotcha. Sorry. Was trying to see the distinction I thought you were making. I get ya now.

Comment: The tone and (level) of detail in this answer feels (to me) like giving legal advice. Does anyone more familiar with the site guidelines know where the line is on this?

Comment: It clearly states not to consider this legal advice and to consult an attorney if OP pursued the situation. No advice, either, simply summarizing linked-to information available to the general public.